# Substitute variable in an array from another array

Tags: groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Using groovy, how can I substitute the value of an array in another array variable?

For eg.:

```
def Env = [
    'Env1',
    'Env2',
    'Env3'
]

def Job = [
 [
    name: "Job1",
    label: "<$Env>",
    action: #!/usr/bin/bash
             blah
             blah          
 ],
 [
    name: "Job2",
    label: "<$Env>",
    action: #!/usr/bin/bash
             blah
             blah
 ]
```

]

I want the **label** field in the second array *Job* to be populated by every item in *Env*

Comment: Your code above should do that https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5170432558759936

Comment: It is substituting $Env with all values in Env at once, I want it to do it one at a time, first Env1 and then Env2 and so on

Comment: So Job1 label should be Env1, Job2 label = Env2...?

Comment: I want Job1 and Job2 to first have Env1 and then Job1 and Job2 to have Env2 and so on until it gets to the end of all Envs. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If the code isn't dynamic you can just do:

```
def Env = ['Env1','Env2', 'Env3']

def Job = [  
[     
    name: "Job1",     
    label: "<${Env[0]}>",     
    action: '#!/usr/bin/bash'
],  
[     
    name: "Job2",     
    label: "<${Env[1]}>",     
    action: '#!/usr/bin/bash'
]
]
```

If it's dynamic you can do:

```
Job.eachWithIndex{ obj, idx ->
    obj.label = Env[idx]
}
```